# How do I move the woocommerce error message where I want?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to move the woocommerce error inside my section. How do I do that? Do I have to change anything in template file? For all error message , i want it to appear before "row-wrap" class.

```html
   

<div class="row">
    <ul class="woocommerce-error">
        <?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
   <li><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></li>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>


    <section class="row-wrap prod-wrap"> 
      <!-- WOOCOMMERCE ERROR appear here -->
   <div class="row-inner">
      <form action="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
      
       </form>
     </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the product, but since you're looking at an html template, you likely can move the `<ul "woocommerce-error">` anywhere you want in that file.

Answer (score 2):

You can move error message on woocommerce's checkout page with jQuery:

```
$('form.checkout.woocommerce-checkout').bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
if ($('ul.woocommerce-error').length) {
    $('ul.woocommerce-error').insertAfter('.place-order .blue-box')//where you want to place it
}});
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this and work well:

```
function move_woocommerce_message(){
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
  add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_print_notices', 35 );  
}
add_filter('wp', 'move_woocommerce_message');
```

Answer (score 0):

The notices are printed by the `wc_print_notices()` function, which is added by WooCommerce to the following hooks:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_before_product_cat_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
```

To move them you must remove them from their existing locations and then add them to a new hook name.

```
function so_34226268_remove_notices(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
    add_action( 'your_new_hook_location_here', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
    add_action( 'another_new_hook_location', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'so_34226268_remove_notices', 1 );
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this for my Cart page, but no luck. I can't find which hook to use to remove the action. Any ideas?

Comment: In WC3.4.x you can't move the notices as they are hard coded via `wc_print_notices();` on the cart page. It appears that this will change in 3.5. See [source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/439fec579c822613af08fa14c6e3347b15594570/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L299)

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a little bit old, but i've fixed it with the following:

```
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'checkout_error', function(){
    jQuery('.woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout').insertAfter('.inner__logo')
} );
```

when you use the following, it will cause a maximum stack error within JQuery.

```
$('form.checkout.woocommerce-checkout').bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
if ($('ul.woocommerce-error').length) {
    $('ul.woocommerce-error').insertAfter('.place-order .blue-box')//where you want to place it
}});
```